# Running mocha on various packages with lerna

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, lerna

I have just started with a mono repo with multiple packages using [lerna](https://lerna.js.org/).

On all my packages I will have unit tests using `mocha`. But as it stands, only one of my packages is ready for unit tests.

From my understanding, shouldn't I be able to only install `mocha` on the root `package.json` and then run `lerna run test` in order to run it only in the packages that have available test scripts in their num packages, correct?

Unfortunately as it stands this is not working.

I have `mocha` installed as a `devDependency` in the root. However, if I do run `lerna run test --scope=myPackage` I get the following message:

> mocha: command not found

Because it is in fact installed in the root, shouldn't it work for all packages? If it isn't the case, what am I missing here? DO I have to install mocha in all of them after all?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the test script from package.json wherever the unit tests are not ready and lerna wont call it.